# Using JavaScript, is it possible to reset a timer's countdown on button click or keypress

Tags: javascript, timer, reset, onkeyup, onmouseup

I'm trying to make a timer-based document that resets .it's countdown anytime I click the mouse or press a button on my keyboard. Due to my relative lack of knowledge in JavaScript however, I don't know what the next step is after making the timer

I'm pretty sure what I need to use is `onkeyup` and `onmouseup` events, but I'm unsure where to put them or what to add to them. Here's the code for the timer.

```js
let mins = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secs = document.getElementById("seconds");
let display = document.getElementById("display");
let start = document.getElementById("start");
let timer;

function displaymin() {
  display.innerHTML =
    (minutes.value > 9 ? minutes.value : "0" + minutes.value) +
    ":" +
    (seconds.value > 9 ? seconds.value : "0" + seconds.value);
}

function watch() {
  start.disabled = true;
  mins.disabled = true;
  secs.disabled = true;
  var date1 = new Date();
  var countDownDate = new Date();
  countDownDate.setTime(
    date1.getTime() +
    minutes.value * 60 * 1000 +
    seconds.value * 1000 +
    1 * 1000
  );

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    display.innerHTML =
      (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) +
      ":" +
      (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    var audio = new Audio("alarm.mp3");

    if (display.innerHTML == "00:00") {
      clearInterval(x);
      audio.play()
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div oninput="displaymin()">
  <input type="number" id="minutes" min="0" max="59" placeholder="mins" /> :
  <input type="number" id="seconds" min="0" max="59" placeholder="secs" />
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
<div>
  <button id="start" onclick="watch()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What variable represents the starting time?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an idiot, could you explain? I'm sorry but JavaScript is still very new to me, so I don't know exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I guess you need to assign some event handlers for clicks and keypresses on the document.  `document.addEventListener('click', () => // code to reset timer)` and `document.addEventListener('keypress', () => // code to reset timer)`